# How to create an array with the values of a nested array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I  have a multi-dimensional array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => nonce
            [value] => 4OdIiR6JhZ,1565652176,9c1abd8d4e7c717bb1c8a27552aabce58b3bf4b3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => firstName
            [value] => Honkey
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => lastName
            [value] => McDonalds
        )
)
```

and I want to get an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [nonce] => 4OdIiR6JhZ,1565652176,9c1abd8d4e7c717bb1c8a27552aabce58b3bf4b3
    [firstName] => Honkey
    [lastName] => McDonalds
)
```

I know that I could accomplish this by doing a `foreach` loop and creating a new array.

```
$newForm = [];
foreach ($something as $index => $item) {
    $newIndex           = $item['name'];
    $newForm[$newIndex] = $item['value'];
}
```

But I am wondering if there is a better way to do this (perhaps using one of PHP's array functions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the 3 parameter form of [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) is perfect for:

```
$output = array_column($input, 'value', 'name');
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [nonce] => 4OdIiR6JhZ,1565652176,9c1abd8d4e7c717bb1c8a27552aabce58b3bf4b3
    [firstName] => Honkey
    [lastName] => McDonalds
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/pOuPO)

Answer (score 0):

With `foreach`,

```
$result = [];
foreach($array as $v){
    $result[$v["name"]] = $v["value"];
}
```

Check [Demo](https://3v4l.org/knWm5)